# How can I parse complex XML to List<string> using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I parse complex XML to List using LINQ in c#?

For example:

```
<para l="3645" t="2387" r="7665" b="2885" alignment="left" li="3240" lsp="exactly" lspExact="492" language="en" styleRef="paraStyle_1_1_62">
                <ln l="3645" t="2370" r="7665" b="2775" baseLine="2775" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="2650" fontFace="Tahoma" fontFamily="swiss" fontPitch="variable" spacing="60" scale="700">
                  <wd l="3645" t="2370" r="4365" b="2775">908</wd>
                  <space />
                  <wd l="4740" t="2370" r="4920" b="2775">W</wd>
                  <space />
                  <wd l="5295" t="2370" r="7665" b="2775">CUMBERLAN</wd>
                </ln>
              </para>
              <para l="4740" t="2895" r="6825" b="3400" alignment="left" li="4392" lsp="exactly" lspExact="504" language="en" styleRef="paraStyle_1_1_62">
                <ln l="4740" t="2895" r="6825" b="3315" baseLine="3300" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="2650" fontFace="Tahoma" fontFamily="swiss" fontPitch="variable" spacing="60" scale="700">
                  <wd l="4740" t="2895" r="5955" b="3315">DUNN,</wd>
                  <space />
                  <wd l="6375" t="2895" r="6825" b="3300">NC</wd>
                </ln>
              </para>
```

The output should be a List whose first index will be the value in between the first `<para>` tag i.e. "908 W CUMBERLN"
the 2nd index will be "DUNN NC"
and so on.

This is my code

```
 doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:/Users/jarvisPC/Desktop/1.xml");

 var data = from q in doc.Descendants("para").Descendants("ln")
            where q.Element("wd") != null
            select new List<string>
            {                           
               q.Element("wd").Value
            };
```

But its reading the first text in between `<wd>` tag i.e. the output is coming as a List whose first index is "908" and 2nd index is "DUNN".

Comment: Are you assigning work for us?

Comment: Don't post images of code please.

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code-writing service. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I have posted my code, can you please help me reagrding this @Zesty.

Comment: @Abhilash also, replace the image with the text of the XML file.

Comment: replaced @zesty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting only the first `<wd>` element.

Use [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

```
var data = from para in doc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Element("wd") != null)
            select new List<string>
            {
                para.Elements("wd").Select(x => x.Value).Aggregate((i, j) => i + " " + j)
            };
```

Output:

> 908 W CUMBERLAN
>
> DUNN, NC